# FragmentStatePagerAdapter memory issue

Tags: android, memory, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm making an application with the ViewPager class and with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter. I've read that the difference between the mentioned adapter and FragmentPagerAdapter is that the later stores all pages in memory at once, whereas FragmentStatePagerAdapter has only 3 loaded in memory at any given time.

So, here is the issue. I have a ViewPager with about 50 pages. There is a fragment on each page with a single ImageView image(and some other elements). After scrolling through around 20 unique pages, I usually get the Out Of Memory Error. So, my question is: How am I supposed to configure FragmentStatePagerAdapter to only have about 3 pages loaded in memory at any given time? This is the code for my adapter:

```
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Song song = mSongs.get(position);
            return PlayFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mSongs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
            View view = (View)o;
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
            view = null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View context, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            imageView.findViewById(R.id.albumimage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), position));

            ((ViewPager) context).addView(imageView);

            return imageView;
        }

        });
```

The destroyItem and instantiateItem methods currently do nothing. I've added them after reading about this from someone else's question. There is no difference as of now if I have these two methods in my code or not.

I've read other questions similar to mine, but I have finally decided to ask a question after having attempted to solve the problem on my own with no good results.

I tried setting the ImageView to null in onDestroy(), but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bitmap` created by `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), position)` has to be released manually by calling `Bitmap.recycle()`

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

I've started using bitmaps as input for ImageView. The code below works fine.

```
albumimg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mSong.getImg());
mImg.setImageBitmap(albumimg);
mImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And this in onDestroy() and onDestroyView():

```
if(albumimg != null) {`albumimg.recycle(); }`
```

Thanks for the help. :)